# Different boolean treatment in string template?

Tags: javascript

```js
const a = 'hi';
const b = 'newTextHI'
const str = `${a.toUpperCase()}${true && `\n${b.toUpperCase()}`}`;
console.log(str);

const c = 'hi';
const d = 'newTextHI'
const str2 = `${c.toUpperCase()}${false && `\n${d.toUpperCase()}`}`;
console.log(str2);
```

`true` will be ignore automatically but `false` will be evaluated as string?

I understand that ternary operator can get what I want, but I don't understand the reason why boolean being treated differently in the above example

Comment: use a ternary instead?

Comment: Use ternary operator, something like: `decider ? <text_you_want> : <empty_string>`

Comment: @DanielLizik: Yeah I understand ternary can get what I want, but I don't understand the reason why boolean being treated differently in the above example

Comment: @Isaac because template literal in js coerces to a string, so `false` comes `"false"`

Comment: @DanielLizik: OH! I've forgotten the first part `false` will be evaluate too! Silly me! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `expression1 && expression2`,

if `expression1` is [**`truthy`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), it will return `expression2` else it will return `expression1`. ([Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description))

Same logic is repeatedly applied if it's chained. It will check until a [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value is found. If not found, the last expression is returned. ([Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation))

```js
// no falsy expressions here
// last expression returned: `string`
console.log(true && `string`)

// short-circuit at false, because what's the point of going further?
console.log(false && `string`) 

// true, 100, "string" are all truthy
// 0 is a falsy value. So, this evaluates until 0 and returns it
console.log(true && 100 && `string` && 0 && "doesn't matter")
```

In your case, you can use the ternary operator instead:

```js
const a = 'hi';
const b = 'newTextHI'
const decider = false;
const str = `${a.toUpperCase()}${decider ? `\n${b.toUpperCase()}` : ``}`;
console.log(str);
```